# Integrate facebook login for already registered users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am integrating facebook login in my application using the example code from the Omniauth documentation

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

```
def self.from_omniauth(hash)
  where(email: hash.info.email).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = hash.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.username = hash.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
  end
end

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook

    # render :text => request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml

    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

I followed the example as it is. However as the code in omniauth_callbacks_controller I'd say if an user is a new to the application then it should follow the else statement and be redirected to user registration url. However what happens is that a new user is created in the database always. Shouldn't I fall in the else statement in case the user has no account yet in my app?

According to the suggested implementation of the method from_omniauth I understand that first_or_create actually creates a new user in the db using the information from facebook. But if that's the case, what is the use of the else option redirecting to new_user_registration_url?

Anything I am not seeing?

Comment: i just read the link. i think the example has added the else part because if you have some other validations on user fields in future, due to which user is not created or some other issues while saving the user and user does not exists in database in that case you have to redirect user to some root. And registration url is the best option to handle that case.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks Athar